# Girls, boys and combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given the following problem: a class room contains 9 boys and 3 girls. Find the number of ways a teacher can select a committee of 4 if there is to be at least 1 girl

The correct answer is: $\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{3}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{9}{2}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{9}{1}=369$

I have trouble to bend my mind around the reason why
$\binom{3}{1}\binom{11}{3}=495$ is the wrong approach.
I choose 1 girl and then I basically pick 4 students of the remaining bunch.

Can anybody point me what my error in reasoning is?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your approach can produce the same committee in different ways (if the committee has more than one girl), so you're overcounting.

Comment: @karl Can you expand a bit more? Thanks

Comment: {Alice;Beth,Carl,Dave} is the same committee as {Beth;Alice,Carl,Dave} but you've counted these as two different committees. A correct solution should count this set exactly once.

Comment: @Karl. Thanks a lot

Comment: Compare to a far simpler problem where the class has only 4 people in it in total, all four of which are girls.  Find the number of ways to select a committee of 4 if at least one of these four girls has to be a girl.  Clearly there is only the one outcome, the one where we select all four of the people in the class.  According to your broken logic, there are $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}=4$ ways.  The punchline is, as usual, that if you break apart by multiplication principle... you are applying some sort of significance to if someone is picked at the first step versus later steps.

Comment: For reference, a somewhat simpler solution in this specific case (*and other cases where we ask for "at least one"*) is to look at the opposite.  The number of committees if we don't care is $\binom{9+3}{4}$.  The number of committees which had no girls is $\binom{9}{4}$, giving the total as $\binom{12}{4}-\binom{9}{4}$

Comment: As a final critique for now, even if your course was labeled "probability" the concept of probability itself does not appear in your problem and so it should not be tagged as such.  You could make this into a probability question by asking "what the probability is that a randomly selected committee has a girl on it", but without that it should just get the combinatorics tag alone.

Answer (score 2):

Fractionating the choosing process the way you have done results in overcounting.

Suppose the girls are Alice, Betty and Carol,  by $\binom31$, you may choose any of the three. Suppose all $3$ girls happen to be chosen, you are counting
Alice | Betty Carol,$\;$ or$\,$ Betty| Alice Carol,$\;$ or$\,$ Carol| Alice Betty

Even if two girls are selected, an overcount will occur.

Only if one girl is selected will it give a correct count.